# Why doesn't Super User get job postings?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I was just wondering why Super User does not have a job listing like some of the other sites (Stack Overflow and Server Fault for example):

[image]

Is there a particular reason this community does not have something similar? Bear with me, as I am fairly new to participating on Stack Exchange.

Anything you can share is welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: Great question! Although in my experience not many jobs are advertised on [so] so for [su] they would probably struggle to sell the advertising space resulting in low quality job listings.

Comment: @Burgi thanks for the input.  I figure there are a lot of open positions for entry level tech support for both hardware and software.  SuperUser definitely has the potential to bring in candidates

Comment: The problem is getting the good, high quality recruiters to use the site for advertising. Those sorts of jobs/recruiters tend to have their own contacts and methods, hence why they are the high quality ones :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is StackExhanges Klinex product, Serverfault is targeted to actual professional Administrators.  Superuser (and say Ask Ubuntu) is targeted to anyone with a on-topic question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Neither does Server Fault, directly. [Stack Overflow Careers is the only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271121/please-don-t-make-careers-developers-only-in-practice).

There's only one real job site, and it serves *everyone* (in theory anyway) - though we've never really had any jobs I've seen that are "Super User specific".

I'd *like* that myself (I'm looking for a job, though more on the starter "serverfaulty" side of things), but it doesn't seem to be on the roadmap as far as I see it. There's a bunch of SO and SE related projects that are probably higher priority.

While Shog talks about eventually having site-specific job sites there, it *feels* unlikely.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I wish you luck in the job hunt!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek : I [suppose you upvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271121/please-don-t-make-careers-developers-only-in-practice) the feature request [that prevent the diesel inside gasoline car behaviour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dRqt005w2Gg#t=105 "just use subtitle for automatic translation") isn’t it ?

Comment: At no point did I state I was completely satisfied with the status quo. I merely linked the appropirate official answer, interpreted it.

Answer (score 7):

My understanding is that the basic philosophy on Stack Exchange is that any advertisement should strictly be interesting for the audience.

Some sites (https://stackoverflow.com/, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, https://serverfault.com/, etc.) mainly attract programmers and IT professionals, so advertisers can target them.

Here on Super User, the majority of users are just users of Windows, Excel, etc., coming from a wide range of professions, and their proficiency with the tools is generally not the driver of their job search.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I think there is more of an entry level IT demographic than you may think.  Although, you are correct about SuperUser being more of a broad spectrum of topics as compared to other QA's

Comment: @CheesusCrust : anyway, with [careers fully merged into Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272487/242800), things goes [like in this famous sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dRqt005w2Gg#t=103 "just use subtitle for automatic translation").